# how to retrieve users based on the selected categories and sub categories from database in laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent-relationship

I would like to begin with the messy things I have done with the database architecture.

[image: tables and relationships]

I have put the fields `title`, `description`, `donation_amount`, in the users table which should have been in a different table. But now if I change this, I would have to change a lot of things.

The ManyToMany relation is already setup between these tables in laravel. I tried to join tables that query builder as well.

There are different roles in the application. We will talk specifically about `Donor` When a `Donor` registers in the Application. It selects multiple categories and sub_categories which stores in `selections` table.
Now when a `donor` logs in to the application. It should only get the records based on the categories selected.
Now I am confused how can I retrieve the users based on the logged in users selected categories and sub_categories.

I have tried joining the tables which works well but it is getting all the results against the joined tables.

```
DB::table("users")->select('users.*')->from('categories')
            ->join('selections','categories.id', '=', 'selections.category_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id','=', 'selections.user_id')
            ->join('sub_categories','sub_categories.id', '=', 'selections.sub_category_id')
            ->where('users.status','approved')->paginate(6);
```

**Relations in the model Category**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'selections');
}
```

**Relations in the model User**

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'selections');
}
```

If there is a way of doing this calling eloquent relationships. I would love the help else It would be evenly nicer to get the job done with the joins I have already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Use has-many-through relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

In other way you can query like this :

```
DB::table("users")->select('users.*')
->whereIn('users.id',function($query) use ($specific_category_id){
   $query->select(''user_id')->from('selections')->where('category_id',$specific_category_id)
})
->where('users.status','approved')->paginate(6);
```

Comment: can you please give an idea? I have tried switching between models. It can get the desired result but I am getting very confused of its behavior.